# Move constructor in initializator list with a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, copy, move, initializer-list

With this sample:

```
// test.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

class mystring : public string { public:
    mystring() = default;

    mystring(const char* c) : string(c) {}

    mystring(mystring& m) : string(m) { cout << "Reference" << endl; }
    mystring(mystring const & m) : string(m) { cout << "Const reference" << endl; }
    mystring(mystring&& m) : string(move(m)) { cout << "Move" << endl; }
};

int main() {
    mystring a;

    vector<mystring> v{ a };
}
```

The ouput is:

```
$ g++ --version | grep "g++"
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2
$ g++ -std=c++11 -fno-elide-constructors test.cpp
$ ./a.out
Reference
Move
Const reference
```

But, if I initialice v with a r-value:

```
vector<mystring> v{"hello"};
```

the output is:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -fno-elide-constructors test.cpp
$ ./a.out
Const reference
```

that means, no copies. With a r-value:

```
vector <mystring> v{mystring()};
```

output:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -fno-elide-constructors test.cpp
$ ./a.out
Move
Move
Const reference
```

I don't understand two things:

- Why with no-raw strings a second move (before the first copy/move) is performed?
- Why with raw strings, no copies of "mystring" are performed?

Comment: "_But, if I initialice v with a r-value:_" I don't think you mean rvalue here

Comment: @JonathanWakely It's a "value", a "unnamed" object, "not-an-lvalue", a "prvalue". I think I mean rvalue here :) If I'm wrong I have to study C++ from the first :P

Comment: OK, but you refer to both `"hello"` and `mystring()` as "_with an r-value_" where it would be useful to distinguish those cases

Comment: But both are r-value, aren't them? The first a constant r-value and the second a modifiable r-value, no?

Comment: My point is that you could refer them as "a string literal" and "an rvalue `mystring`" to distinguish the fact that they are two very different things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

N.B. raw strings means something different in C++11, I think you mean string literal if you're talking about `"hello"`

> - Why with raw strings, no copies of "mystring" are performed?

Eh? There's one copy, that's why it prints `Const Reference`.

```
vector<mystring> v{"hello"};
```

The braced-init-list initializes the `std::initializer_list<mystring>` constructor parameter with a single element, which is constructed using the `mystring(const char* c)` constructor, then that element is copied into the vector using the `mystring(const mystring&)` constructor, which prints `Const Reference`. Pretty simple.

> - Why with no-raw strings a second move (before the first copy/move) is performed?

How can the second move be before the first move?! :)

It is an implementation detail of how the `initializer_list` is constructed, which normally wouldn't matter because the extra moves would be elided.

```
vector <mystring> v{mystring()};
```

This creates a temporary `mystring` using the default constructor, then creates `std::initializer_list<mystring>` with a single element, which is constructed using the `mystring(mystring&&)` constructor with the temporary as its argument. That move construction prints `Move`. There's another move done internally, printing `Move` again. Then the `initializer_list` element is copied into the vector as before, printing `Const Reference`.

To answer your comment:

The extra move you see also happens in the first case, but in that case the type being moved is `const char*` so it doesn't print `Move` i.e. the statement `std::vector<mystring>{ expr };` can be thought of as:

```
auto tmp = expr;
mystring tmparray[] = { std::move(tmp) };
std::initializer_list<mystring> init_list( tmparray, 1 };
std::vector<mystring> v(init_list);
```

When `expr` is `a` (which is a non-const lvalue) creating `tmp` prints `Reference` then creating `tmparray` prints `Move`then copying `tmparray[0]` into the vector prints `Const Reference`.

when `expr` is `"hello"` creating the elements of `tmp` doesn't print anything, and creating `tmparray` calls `mystring(const char*)` which doesn't print anything, then copying `tmparray[0]` into the vector prints `Const Reference`.

When `expr` is `mystring()` creating `tmp` prints `Move` then creating `tmparray` prints `Move` then copying `tmparray[0]` into the vector prints `Const Reference`

With a two element braced-init-list like `{ expr1, expr2 }` it can be though of as:

```
auto tmp1 = expr1;
auto tmp2 = expr2;
mystring tmparray[] = { std::move(tmp1), std::move(tmp2) };
std::initializer_list<mystring> init_list( tmparray, 2 };
std::vector<mystring> v(init_list);
```

So if you use `{ "hello", mystring() }` you get `Move` printed once by `tmp2` and `Move` printed once by `tmparray` and `Const Reference` printed twice by the elements of `v`.

Of course normally all of this would be elided away, so there are no unnecessary copies or moves.  `-fno-elide-constructors` is not really useful except for finding out what would happen, but doesn't actually happen!

Comment: And why with {mystring()} the temporary is copied, and with {"hello"} the temporary (mystring("hello")) isn't copied?

Comment: But if I have a list like {"hello", mystring()}? auto would be of type "mystring" and thus "hello" would be "mystring" in the first line of your code, and moved in the second line. It doesn't match. But I can see is implementation defined. Perhaps, the first two lines are executed for each element in the list but not like arrays. In this form the description match with the "experience".

Comment: Yes, actually `tmparray` shouldn't be an array, it's more like `tuple<T...>`, so each element can be a different type. Given `{ "hello", mystring }` it would be `tuple<const char*, mystring>` so would print `Move` once, then `tmparray2` would print `Move` once as well. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You did not correctly label the move constructor as `noexcept`.

Comment: What is the relation of noexcept with my problem? After changing it, same results.

Comment: It's a very good idea to label it `noexcept` but not actually required, and not incorrect to leave it out (though it does prevent certain important optimisations that containers can do with elements that are nothrow-move-constructible)